# Error al intentar instalar backports: "No matching distribution found for backports"

Tags: python

Estoy intentado utilizar `backports` probando el código dado por Sachin Joglekar [en un proyecto sobre redes neuronales convolucionales para proyecto para clasificar los comentarios tóxicos](https://medium.com/@srjoglekar246/first-time-with-kaggle-a-convnet-to-classify-toxic-comments-with-keras-ef84b6d18328).

```
from backports import csv
```

pero cuando intento cargarlo con python2.7 o python3 tengo errores :

Con python3 tengo las siguientes :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Kaggle$ sudo pip install backports.weakref
The directory '/home/mike/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/mike/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: backports.weakref in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

mike@mike-thinks:~/Kaggle$ sudo pip install backports
The directory '/home/mike/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/mike/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting backports
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement backports (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for backports
```

Con python2.7:

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Kaggle$ python medium.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "medium.py", line 1, in <module>
    from backports import csv
ImportError: cannot import name csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En PyPI `backports` no es realmente un paquete que contenga todos los *backports* existentes, solo existe para reservar el espacio de nombres `backports` para paquetes con estos fines.

Supongo que quieres usar el módulo csv de Python 3 en Python 2 mediante su *backport*. En este caso debes instalar el módulo [`backports.csv`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backports.csv) en Python 2:

```
sudo pip install backports.csv
```

Esto suponiendo que tu intérprete por defecto sea Python 2.7 como se deduce de lo que te muestra la consola. Recuerda usar `pip3 install` para instalar módulos en Python 3.x. Personalmente prefiero instalar vía `python3 -m pip intall...`/ `python2.7 -m pip install...` / `<Ruta a interprete cualquiera con pip instalado> -m pip install...` / etc, es más explícito.

> **Nota:** no es recomendable instalar librerías directamente en la instalación de Python del SO vía sudo. Siempre es mejor usar un entorno virtual para estos fines e instalar en el los paquetes manteniendo limpia y a salvo la instalación del sistema.